# mysql, unknown column in field list

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, syntax

i have a very simple db

```
create table if not exists customerdata(id VARCHAR(40) primary key, obj blob)
```

one procedure for updating this table

```
create procedure saveCustomer(IN customerid VARCHAR(40), IN customerobj blob)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO customerdata (id, obj) VALUES(customerid, customerobj)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE obj = VALUES(customerobj);
END
```

using jdbc to call this procedure

```
byte[] byteArray = bos.toByteArray();
String sql = "call saveCustomer(?,?)";
ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1,customerid);
ps.setBytes(2,byteArray);
ps.execute();
```

but as a result im getting following exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbcd4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'customerobj' in 'field list'
```

same error occurs when i try to call the procedure from mysql workbench.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `on duplicate key`.  It should be either:

```
INSERT INTO customerdata (id, obj) VALUES(customerid, customerobj)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE obj = customerobj;
```

or:

```
INSERT INTO customerdata (id, obj) VALUES(customerid, customerobj)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE obj = VALUES(obj);
```

The `values()` statement uses the column name in the table, not the value itself.

I would also recommend that you prefix arguments with something like `v_`, so they are less likely to be confused with column names.